# Posting a comment on page as yourself (not the page) using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to build a commenting system for posts that are synchronized between Facebook and a website.

As of now, everything works fine, except when I'm logged in with a user that is an admin of the page, it posts as the page, no matter what I try to do.

I first went on my page settings and unchecked "Always comment and post on your page as Testing Page, even when using Facebook as X."

My code is as following:

```
// fb-id is usually POST_ID

FB.api($comments.data('fb-id') + '/comments', 'post', {
    message: $('textarea', $comments).val(),   // this works fine
    from: FB.getUserID()   // no effect
}, function(){

    // callback here

});
```

I've even tried to revoke my permissions doing a DELETE on /me/permissions and get a new token with just publish_stream, but still, it posts as the page.

I just tried using the Graph API Explorer, from there, if I post to POST_ID/comments using an access token with just publish_stream, it also posts from as my page, and not as my logged in user.

Also just tried the FB PHP SDK, with the same parameters, different way to get the access_token, and same thing happens.

Anyone knows how I force FB to post the comment as the logged in user? Or is this a Facebook bug? I've saw 1-2 other person online that was complaining about this problem, but no fix.

**EDIT** The bug report at Facebook got accepted and assigned. This question can be closed now, as it is a valid bug.

Comment: This question is related, but answer is not helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329468/how-to-post-a-comment-on-facebook-page-as-user-not-as-page

Comment: I would recommend [opening a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and see what officials say as well...

Comment: That's probably what I'll have to do. I'll wait until the bounty expires and post this problem to Facebook.

Comment: I've noticed that for some features, after you enable/disable the feature, you have to forcibly grab a fresh access token AFTER the change was made.  I have seen this fix many issues.  Maybe it might solve this as well?  Worth a try.

Comment: Lol... trying to create the bug report on Facebook, but I get a Internal Server Error when trying to create the bug.

Comment: Bug report created: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/498901773487555

Comment: Are you setting the token anywhere before hand?  If so you may need to use the api to set the token to a user token.

Comment: You must report the bug in bug reporting page as well. :)

Comment: Would love to see an answer to this. Remember to update your bug report (you have received a response from Alvin Sng).

Comment: @DanGreaves Currently away for Christmas, however, I did provide the information that Alvin requested

Comment: Anyone still has a problem with this? They said they fixed it, but it's absolutely no different for me personally.